# heroku toolbelt standalone version seeking ruby

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have installed standalone version of heroku toolbelt from this site.

```
https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone
```

I followed all its instruction properly. 
when i give following command i get the result like this

```
[student@localhost ~]$ which heroku
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

But when I enter

```
[student@localhost ~]$ heroku login
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Thus I get confused why this standalone version is asking or searching for ruby.
I am a python developer so has no idea about ruby.

Comment: what do you get if you do `which ruby`?

Comment: [student@localhost ~]$ which ruby
/usr/bin/which: no ruby in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/student/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools:/home/student/.local/bin:/home/student/bin:/home/student/bin:/home/student/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools)

Comment: Try installing ruby, you'll need it to get heroku work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku toolbelt contains the [Heroku CLI](https://github.com/heroku/heroku), which is currently written in Ruby.

Therefore, you need Ruby in order to perform any Heroku command using the Heroku CLI. Heroku is working to replace the Ruby CLI with a [library written in Go](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli), that will likely be compiled and lift the runtime dependency to an interpreter.

I always worked with environments where Ruby was installed, hence I'm not sure if the toolbelt is supposed to install Ruby when not found.

Anyway, the easiest solution is to install Ruby in your machine.